# SQL UPDATE statement throws error "Invalid use of group function"

Tags: sql

The SQL `UPDATE` statement keeps throwing an error

> Invalid use of group function

Code:

```
UPDATE client
SET car_id = '6', 
    car_name = 'Wedding Limousine', 
    rentdate = '2019-07-27', 
    days = '2', 
    hire_cost_total = '41.99'
WHERE client_id = MAX(client_id);
```

I think the `WHERE client_id = MAX(client_id)` is incorrect but I am not sure how to resolve this error.

I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the row with the maximun `client_id`:

```
UPDATE client
SET car_id = '6', car_name = 'Wedding Limousine', rentdate = '2019-07-27', 
days = '2', hire_cost_total = '41.99'    
WHERE client_id = (
  SELECT t.client_id FROM (SELECT MAX(client_id) as client_id FROM client) as t
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should obatin the max client_id  using a subquery

```
UPDATE client
SET car_id = '6'
    , car_name = 'Wedding Limousine'
    , rentdate = '2019-07-27'
    , days = '2'
    , hire_cost_total = '41.99'
WHERE client_id = (
  select MAX(client_id)
  from client 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
UPDATE client
    SET car_id = '6',
        car_name = 'Wedding Limousine',
        rentdate = '2019-07-27', 
        days = '2',
        hire_cost_total = '41.99'
    ORDER BY client_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```